# How to localize flutter for web app name and description?

Tags: flutter, localization, flutter-web

Is there a simple way to localize app name and description for a flutter for web project?
I was thinking of a script in the `index.html` file that detects the language of the browser and overrides a default value, but am not convinced of this solution and was wondering if there is a better way to localize the `manifest.json`.